# How can I find the largest value of two columns located in different sheets?

Tags: excel-2010

I have two columns of data and I need to find the largest value without merging the columns. I tried `LARGE(('Sheet 1'!A:A):('Sheet 1'!B:B);k)`, which works when the columns are located in the same sheet.

But `LARGE(('Sheet 1'!A:A):('Sheet 2'!B:B);k)` returns `#VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest find the largest of each sheet individually, then the largest of those two results. Something like:

```
=MAX(MAX(A:A),MAX([Book1.xls]Sheet2!$B:$B))
```

However a shorter version should give the same result:

```
=MAX(A:A,Sheet2!B:B)
```

where I have assumed the sheets are in the same book.